# Comparar Salário dentre as Arrays()

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte Query:

```
SELECT * FROM folhapagamento_storages WHERE idFolhaParametro = '1' AND valor_min >= '1083.4' AND valor_max <= '1083.4'
```

Só que o retorno sempre será 0, o que estaria fazendo de errado? Qual seria a lógica correta?

Neste caso, precisaria retornar apenas a faixa 1, como result, e vem zerado... 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM folhapagamento_storages WHERE idFolhaParametro = 1 AND valor_min >= 1083.4 AND valor_max <= 1083.4
```

### <=

Tem que colocar `<=` (menor igual) na consulta do `valor_max`. E número decimal não precisa de aspas.

Comment: Dá mesma forma, o resultado vem zerado, nesta sua condição

Comment: Olhando melhor agora seus registros realmente não vai retornar nada essa sua consulta. Nenhum valor mínimo ou máximo adere a sua condição. Agora, se você colocar um `OR` no lugar do `AND` entre os valores vai retornar registros.

Answer (score 0):

Você está consultando utilizando: valor_max = '1083.4'. O correto seria <= '1083.4'.

Query completa:

```
SELECT * FROM folhapagamento_storages WHERE idFolhaParametro = '1' AND valor_min >= '1083.4' AND valor_max <= '1083.4'
```